# Android: How to resize contents of an ImageView to the same dimensions of another ImageView's contents?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am trying to resize the contents of an `ImageView` to the same dimensions of another `ImageView`'s contents. For example, say I have the two following images, one of which is horizontally oriented and the other is vertically oriented:

**Vertical Image**:

[image]

**Horizontal Image**:

[image]

I want to resize the vertical image to the horizontal image, like this:

[image]

Most importantly, the **dimensions of the `ImageViews` and their contents need to be the same**, as shown in the below screenshot of the horizontal `ImageView`:

[image]

I tried retrieving the dimensions of the `BitMap` for the horizontal `ImageView` and rescaling the vertical `ImageView`'s `BitMap` to the horizontal `BitMap`, but the dimensions retrieved for the `BitMap` always show the original horziontal photo's dimensions, not the dimensions of the photo scaled to fit into the horizontal `ImageView`.

Below is my code of what I have been working so far:

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/slider_screen_photo_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dip"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/slider_screen_image_1_box"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="370dp"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/slider_screen_image_2_box"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="370dp"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java (Retrieving horizontal ImageView's BitMap dimensions)**:

```
    ImageView sliderPreviewBox = null;

    if (photoNum == 1) {
        sliderPreviewBox = findViewById(R.id.slider_screen_image_1_box);
    }
    if (photoNum == 2) {
        sliderPreviewBox = findViewById(R.id.slider_screen_image_2_box);
    }

    Drawable drawable = sliderPreviewBox.getDrawable();
    int width = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
    int height = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

onCreate..

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(MyPath);
try {
    int rotation = getExifOrientation(MyPath);
    Log.d(TAG, "\n--- Rotation of the image " + name + " is: " + rotation);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Bitmap rot_bitmap = rotateBitmap(MyPath, bitmap);
imageView.setImageBitmap(rot_bitmap);
```

After:

```
// To get the original orientation of the image
public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(String src, Bitmap bitmap) {
    try {
        // Getting the orientation of the image, there are 6 cases:
        // The Exif specification defines an Orientation Tag to indicate the orientation of the camera relative to the captured scene
        // Source: http://sylvana.net/jpegcrop/exif_orientation.html
        int rotation = getExifOrientation(src);
        if (rotation == 1) { return bitmap; }
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        switch (rotation) {
            case 2: matrix.setScale(-1, 1); break;
            case 3: matrix.setRotate(180); break;
            case 4: matrix.setRotate(180); matrix.postScale(-1, 1); break;
            case 5: matrix.setRotate(90); matrix.postScale(-1, 1); break;
            case 6: matrix.setRotate(90); break;
            case 7: matrix.setRotate(-90); matrix.postScale(-1, 1); break;
            case 8: matrix.setRotate(-90); break;
            default: return bitmap;
        }
        // Creating a bitmap after its rotation and recycling the original one
        try {
            Bitmap oriented = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            // on low-memory system such as Android, must be attention to add bitmap.recycle(); to avoid the memory leak exception
            bitmap.recycle();
            return oriented;
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return bitmap;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;
}


// function to get the orientation of bitmap
private static int getExifOrientation(String src) throws IOException {
    int orientation = 1;
    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(src);
    String orientationString=exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
    try { assert orientationString != null;
        orientation = Integer.parseInt(orientationString); }
    catch(NumberFormatException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        return orientation;
    }
```

Comment: Why would I want to rotate the image?

Comment: In your case it will not rotate the photo. But if you have a photo with another orientation, it will. And to adapt to ImageView you can play with: android: scaleType = "centerInside"